# Mapstruct: how to qualify an IterableMapping function

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a mapper between an entity and a DTO:

```
@Mapper(componentModel="cdi", uses = { RegionMapper.class })
public interface ClusterMapper {
    @Mapping(target="regions", ignore=true)
    ClusterDto map(Cluster entity);

    ClusterDto mapWithRegions(Cluster entity);
}
```

The first mapping function is a "simple mapping" to list entities, the second one is for a detailed view. I would like to have the List equivalent, so I have an annotation:

```
@Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Simple {
}
```

And add this qualifier to the first mapping function, and to the List function:

```
@Mapper(componentModel="cdi", uses={RegionMapper.class})
public interface ClusterMapper {
    @Simple // <====
    @Mapping(target="regions", ignore=true)     
    ClusterDto map(Cluster entity);

    ClusterDto mapWithRegions(Cluster entity);

    @IterableMapping(qualifiedBy = Simple.class) // <====
    List<ClusterDto> map(List<Cluster> entities);

}
```

but even with the `@Simple` annotation, I have an error message:

> Ambiguous mapping methods found for mapping collection element to...

How can I made the `List map(List)` function "choose" the first mapping function ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I made a mistake: for my `@Simple` annotation, I have imported `javax.inject.Qualifier` instead of `org.mapstruct.Qualifier`.